# How to re-direct output to same file always?

Tags: perl

I trying to redirect output to same text file. But I'm not able to do. please help me

**code**

```
foreach my $config (sort keys %{$details}) {
  if (exists $details->{$config}) {
    foreach my $project (sort keys %{ $details->{$config} }) {
      system( "$path/perl ./bin/export_from_ddts.pl 2> \"\'>>\' ./logs/system_error.txt\"" );
      system( "$path/perl ./bin/convert_to_csv.pl  2> \"\'>>\' ./logs/system_error.txt\"" );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system(qq($path/perl ./bin/export_from_ddts.pl 2>>./logs/system_error.txt));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `print` the string you are passing to `system`. As it stands you are using

```
/path/to/perl ./bin/export_from_ddts.pl 2> "'>>' ./logs/system_error.txt"
```

which is clearly nonsense.